# Getting error "cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>" when trying to convert Unix timestamp (int) to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, unix

I have a table called 'Generic' with a date column called 'createdDate' with values as Unix timestamp. The datatype of the Unix timestamp values are currently int64.

I would like to create another column in the dataframe called 'createdDate2' which would contain the Unix dates in a datetime format (e.g. YY/MM/DD)

I am running the following code:

```
import datetime
generic['createdDate2'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(generic.createdDate).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You give the entire dataframe to the function that only needs to take a single integer, so you get an error. You can use the code below.

```
generic['createdDate2']=pd.to_datetime(generic['createdDate'], unit='s')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion (defining  Pandas as pd) but now get the following error:

'cannot convert input with unit 's''

I tried using 'm' as a unit but get the same error

Comment: Can you try "ms" instead of "s"